# Undefined references - VTK and make

Tags: c++, vtk, undefined-reference

Some includes just work fine and some doesn't.

I'm using these in my cpp:

```
#include <vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkNew.h>
#include <vtkPolyDataMapper.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkSphereSource.h>
#include <vtkCylinderSource.h>
#include <QVTKOpenGLWidget.h>
#include <QVTKWidget.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkVersion.h>
#include <vtkParametricFunctionSource.h>
#include <vtkTubeFilter.h>
#include <vtkParametricSpline.h>
#include <vtkDoubleArray.h>
#include <vtkPoints.h>
#include <vtkPolyData.h>
#include <vtkPointData.h>
#include <vtkActor.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
#include <vtkCylinderSource.h>
#include <vtkProperty.h>
```

**Errors #1:**

```
undefined reference to `vtkDebugLeaksManager::~vtkDebugLeaksManager()'
undefined reference to `vtkObjectFactoryRegistryCleanup::vtkObjectFactoryRegistryCleanup()'
```

The following ones are causing this error for example:

```
#include <vtkSphereSource.h>
#include <vtkCylinderSource.h>
#include <vtkParametricFunctionSource.h>
```

The code uses a lot of makefiles so i can't share everything with you but i guess the following parts might be helpful:

```
LIBS= -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lvtkViewsQt-8.0 -lvtkViewsCore-8.0
```

**Errors #2**

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libvtksys-8.0.so.1, needed by /.../libvtkCommonCore-8.0.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

I guess this is the main problem here which causes the following additional errors

```
.../libvtkCommonCore-8.0.so: undefined reference to `vtksys::Directory::Directory()'
.../libvtkCommonCore-8.0.so: undefined reference to `vtksys::SystemToolsManager::~SystemToolsManager()'
.../libvtkCommonCore-8.0.so: undefined reference to `vtksys::DynamicLoader::LastError()'
.../libvtkCommonCore-8.0.so: undefined reference to `vtksys::DynamicLoader::CloseLibrary(void*)'
.../libvtkCommonCore-8.0.so: undefined reference to `vtksys::SystemTools::Strucmp(char const*, char const*)'
.../libvtkCommonCore-8.0.so: undefined reference to `vtksys::Directory::GetNumberOfFiles() const'
.../libvtkCommonCore-8.0.so: undefined reference to `vtksys::SystemToolsManager::SystemToolsManager()'
.../libvtkCommonCore-8.0.so: undefined reference to `vtksys::Directory::~Directory()'
.../libvtkCommonCore-8.0.so: undefined reference to `vtksys::Directory::GetFile(unsigned long) const'
.../libvtkCommonCore-8.0.so: undefined reference to `vtksys::DynamicLoader::GetSymbolAddress(void*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
.../libvtkCommonCore-8.0.so: undefined reference to `vtksys::DynamicLoader::OpenLibrary(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It happens when i want to use the following:

```
LIBS= (as above) -lvtkCommonCore-8.0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At first, be aware of the difference between broken includes vs. link errors. Missing/not-found includes cause compiler errors. The errors shown in the question are link errors. At second, adding more includes to C++ source may cause that you get more link errors as the compiler may compile additional things which have to be linked also. Concerning the ld warning about `libvtksys-8.0.so.1`: the `libvtkCommonCore-8.0.so` may need symbols provided by `libvtksys-8.0.so.1`. Hence, I would consider this warning.

Comment: Btw. it's a while ago that I worked on *ix but I remember that the order of libraries (`-l...`) sometimes was important. I'm really not sure whether this is relevant in your case. Maybe, this was a specialty of these ancient OSF-Motif/X11 things we used that time.

Comment: A simple thumb-rule to recognize compile vs. link errors: Compiler errors usually start with file/line of source code (except that it cannot even find a C++ file to compile). Linker errors are rather prefixed by an object or lib file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That linker warning message is pretty clear, it suggests you link `libvtksys-8.0.so.1`.

Find out the full path to the directory where that file is located, and then add the following to your linker command lines:

```
-L<dir> -Wl,-rpath=<dir> -lvtksys-8.0
```